Enable/disable editable field based on another editable field value in the grid
In my Rails 7 application, I have a Stimulus JS controller that uses AG-Grid to create a table. Each row in the table has an edit button, allowing editing of EDITABLE_FIELDS which are:
const EDITABLE_FIELDS = [
  "cheque_number",
  "comment",
  "payment_amount",
  "payment_date",
  "payment_method",
]

The thing is that cheque_number should be editable only when payment_method is CHEQUE. So I've got below grid options to make it work:
// https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/reference-data/#using-the-refdata-property
function buildEditablePaymentMethodsCollDef(paymentMethods) {
  return {
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      values: Object.keys(paymentMethods),
      useFormatter: true
    },
    editable: true,
    refData: paymentMethods,
    cellRenderer(params) {
      return paymentMethods[params.value]
    },
}
(...)

const columnOptions = {
  columnDefs: {
    cheque_number: { ...EDITABLE_TEXT_COL_DEF, cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 300, sortable: true, editable: params => params.data.payment_method === 'CHEQUE' },
    (...)
    payment_method: { cellClass: 'font-mono', maxWidth: 300, sortable: true },`

It works well, but payment_method is also an editable field. So, when a user changes it to CHEQUE (chosen from the dropdown), the cheque number field should become available as well. Currently, if the payment method is CHEQUE by default, it works fine. However, when a user changes it from, say, Wire to Cheque, the editable form for the cheque number doesn’t show up.

Here is an easy fix that might help
Define the Column Definitions:
Define the column definitions with the necessary properties. Make sure the cheque_number field's editable property depends on the payment_method.
Add Event Listeners:
Add an event listener to handle changes in the payment_method field. When this field is changed, refresh the rows to update the editable state of the cheque_number field.
Refresh the Rows:
Use the AG-Grid API to refresh the rows when the payment_method is changed.
const EDITABLE_FIELDS = [
 "cheque_number",
  "comment",
  "payment_amount",
  "payment_date",
  "payment_method",
]

function buildEditablePaymentMethodsCollDef(paymentMethods) {
  return {
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      values: Object.keys(paymentMethods),
      useFormatter: true
    },
    editable: true,
    refData: paymentMethods,
    cellRenderer(params) {
      return paymentMethods[params.value]
    },
  }
}

const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Cheque Number",
    field: "cheque_number",
    cellClass: 'font-mono',
    maxWidth: 300,
    sortable: true,
    editable: params => params.data.payment_method === 'CHEQUE'
  },
  {
    headerName: "Payment Method",
    field: "payment_method",
    cellClass: 'font-mono',
    maxWidth: 300,
    sortable: true,
    editable: true,
    cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
    cellEditorParams: {
      values: ['CHEQUE', 'WIRE', 'OTHER'], // Add all possible payment methods here
    },
    onCellValueChanged: params => {
      if (params.colDef.field === 'payment_method') {
        params.api.refreshCells({
          rowNodes: [params.node],
          force: true,
          columns: ['cheque_number']
        });
      }
    }
  },
  {...}
];


const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  ...
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});

